# I have problem when get custom field value from contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, contact-form-7

I have trouble when I used this code below to get value form custom field of post type = post

```
[dynamichidden chapter "CF7_get_post_var key='file_download'"]

[dynamichidden dynamichidden-508 "CF7_get_custom_field key='file_download'"]
```

In the picture below, I set return value is File URL

http://prntscr.com/ngjrpn

So I got email with ID value. How can I get URL value of this case.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this contact form 7 extension**

https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/

This extension provide easly way get the value:--

(i). [CF7_GET key=’value1’]

(ii). [dynamictext dynamicname “CF7_POST key=’value2'”]

Comment: I used it, and my problem happened when I got email without URL link.